# Tools to debug a pyqt5 interface that crashes after specific event

Tags: python, windows, pyqt, pyqt5

I have an interface in PyQt5 that crashes when moving a handle too fast (if done slowly, everything is fine), with no error message. My debug capacities reach their limits as the various functions tested separately work, manually and automatically. It may be caused by a memory leak.

Is there a way to debug such an issue?

Thanks in advance!

settings :

- Windows 10
- python 3.8.6
- PyQt 5.12.3

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "moving a handle too fast" shouldn't cause anything like this, unless you're doing wrong things (such as using threading on the UI). Did you try to simply run the program in a terminal or prompt?

Comment: thanks for your replies, I finally reached the problematic function continuing to dig with pdb and breakpoints(). It is QCoreApplication.processEvents(), which I don't master currently

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use any decent IDE (ex: pycharm) to check where you connect your event "handle moved" and see why it crashes.